# Relation programmingError

Tags: python, django, model, relationship

I have model code for which migrations have successfully created and passed:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser


class Employee(AbstractUser):
    probation = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    position = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)

    groups = None
    user_permissions = None


class Order(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    employee = models.ForeignKey('employee', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

after which I registered them in the admin panel

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Employee, Order

@admin.register(Employee)
class EmployeeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'probation', 'position')
    list_filter = ('probation', 'position')
    search_fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email')

@admin.register(Order)
class OrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'employee')
    list_filter = ('employee',)
    search_fields = ('name', 'employee__username', 'employee__first_name', 'employee__last_name')
```

then when I try to add a new employee through the admin panel, I get an error

```
relation "main_employee" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count" FROM "main_employee"
                                          ^
```

Please tell me what is wrong with my code, I will be grateful

Answer (score 0):

Since I still had an empty database, I simply reset postgres completely, rerolled the migrations and this code worked, maybe something in the database was preventing it